# Dropdown Values Option with Multi Store Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, dropdown-attribute, mobile

I have some dropdowns I'm using on a mobile form using getSelectValues. However, if I use Frontend Options as well, in this case I'm using values
Yes/No for Admin and C/B for Store 2, it changes the value when I save. Strange. See below.

Here is the Select values getting called.

> $missing_charger_values = $this->getSelectValues('missing_charger');
>
> $missing_battery_values = $this->getSelectValues('missing_battery');

**Before save**[image]

**After Save**
[image]

Here is the code populate the values. If I refresh is goes back to normal until I save again.

```
<div>
            <label for="product[missing_charger]"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Missing Charger') ?></label>
            <?php if(!empty($missing_charger_values)):?>
            <select name="product[missing_charger]" id="product[missing_charger]" required="required">
                <?php foreach($missing_charger_values as $value): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value['value']?>" <?php if($product->getData('missing_charger') == $value['value']) echo "selected='selected'"?>><?php echo $value['label']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

<div>
            <label for="product[missing_battery]"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Missing Battery') ?></label>
            <?php if(!empty($missing_battery_values)):?>
            <select name="product[missing_battery]" id="product[missing_battery]" required="required">
                <?php foreach($missing_battery_values as $value): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value['value']?>" <?php if($product->getData('missing_battery') == $value['value']) echo "selected='selected'"?>><?php echo $value['label']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough. Incase this happens to anyone else. Just stop it from loading other stores.

```
$missing_charger='missing_charger';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($missing_charger)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$missing_charger_values = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 

$missing_battery='missing_battery';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($missing_battery)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$missing_battery_values = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```